# Office apps are not integrated well in W10M?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-535, system-apps, office

I have recently upgraded my Lumia 535 on Windows 10 Mobile. After upgradation the **Office** in WP8.1 has been replaced by three discrete apps (Word, Excel and PowerPoint) in W10M . But the issue is that these apps are not working in that native way in which the Office worked. Whenever I try to open an office-associated file(.docx, .ppt, .pptx etc), say word document, notification occurs.

[image]

If I tap **yes** it drags me to the Word-app-page in the store where no button of **install, get or update**  is present. Instead there is **launch** button. tapping on which opens Word app but don't induces that file. I manually have to tap on **Browse** button and go to the specific location of the file in order to open it. Similarly I have to **save** an email-attachment to my phone first then I have to open **Word ** again and browse to the location I have saved the file  There is no direct method to open them. Any solution? I have upgraded by official "Upgrade Advisor App" and my phone's L535DS running november update.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Office apps?

Comment: I have tried this only for Word app not the others but I am sure that wouldn't work as it didin't work for Word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still running 1511 version it seems. A lot of bugs has been fixed on Anniversary update i.e)version 1607.

Do the following:

1. Update Windows 10 Mobile to version 1607.
2. Install any pending updates for Office on Store.
3. If things didn't work after that, try uninstalling and re-installing the office apps.
4. If nothing works out perform a hard reset.

---

***Note :*** It is always preferable to perform a hard reset after upgrading to Windows Phone 8.1 to Windows 10. Many people have reported strange problems after the upgrade which are solved by a hard reset.

Comment: But resetting will set it back to WP8.1. Isn't it?

Comment: @User5 No it will not. It will reset phone memory, apps, data,etc... The OS version will be left unchanged. It is like that you will get a new version of OS you currently have.

Comment: Oh it sounds good.......I'll try. And @Kolappan Nathan what you should try is to help me out over same prolem with another app :D . I am also having trouble for pdf files. See my new question.

Comment: Updation was made available today and I have installed it , resolved many issues. Thanks. But how did you find that version?

Comment: @User5 The updated version was released a month ago. It was released in waves or in various phases. Not everyone receives it early. The Windows 10 Version 1607 is yet to roll out to some phone models. It is lucky you received it in time.